# Get current user id from Cloud Functions for Firebase ( PubSub trigger)

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

When i need the current user id in the client side , I can use: `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid`.

How can i get the current user id in cloud functions (Pub Sub trigger)?

```
exports.sendPushNotification = functions.pubsub.schedule("* * * * *")
.onRun(async (context) => {
  const today = new Date();
  const date = today.getFullYear()+"-"+(today.getMonth()+1)+
  "-"+today.getDate();

  const query = await db.collection("posts")
      .where("date", "==", date)
      .where("idUser", "==", i need here to call my current user id)
      .get();

  query.forEach(async (snapshot) => {
    sendNotification(snapshot.data().idUser, snapshot.data().title);
  });
});
```

Comment: While dharmaraj has answered your question, what you are using this trigger for is better achieved using a [Cloud Firestore `onCreate` trigger](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#trigger_a_function_when_a_new_document_is_created) which will give you the post that was created and who created it. However, I'm unsure as to why you are sending a notification about the post to the person who posted it.

Comment: I'm sending a notification to the person who posted it because they are posting an invoice. and on the due date of the invoice, it receives a push notification to remember the due date.

Comment: @WafaBergaoui I am guessing you want to send a notification to users if their invoice is pending. Please share a screenshot of Firestore document of an invoice where the the due data is being stored.

Comment: this is the screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYIgD.png

Comment: @WafaBergaoui I have added a workaround that you can use, if the answer was helpful you can accept it by clicking tick icon so that others know it is resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot get any UID in a scheduled cloud function. That function is not invoked by a user. It's just being invoked periodically based on your schedule. The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#properties_1) says:

> This field is only populated for Realtime Database triggers and
> Callable functions. For an unauthenticated user, this field is null.
> For Firebase admin users and event types that do not provide user
> information, this field does not exist.

The context object in this case looks something like this:

```
{
  "eventId": "eventId",
  "timestamp": "2021-05-16T09:21:00.505Z",
  "eventType": "google.pubsub.topic.publish",
  "params": {},
  "resource": {
    "name": "projects/<project-id>/topics/firebase-schedule-scheduledFunctionCrontab-us-central1",
    "service": "pubsub.googleapis.com",
    "type": "type.googleapis.com/google.pubsub.v1.PubsubMessage"
  }
}
```

To get all users with due date passed you can use this query:

```
const snapshot = admin.firestore().collections("posts").where("data", "<=", Date.now()).get()
const userIds = snapshots.docs.map(post => post.data().idUser)
//Array of users IDs of posts with due date passed
```

Do note I have used [UNIX Timestamp](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/) instead of the date as a string. Then you can performs actions for users with those UIDs as needed.

Comment: It means need to add the uid in params right ?

Comment: @DipanSharma users cannot invoke a Scheduled cloud function so it doesn't have UID in the context. It is invoked by Pub/Sub triggers. Checkout [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext). The context object will contain auth info only if it is triggered by rtdb triggers or is a callable function.

Comment: Yeah getting your point but there must some way where we can store or get uid :(

Comment: @DipanSharma it depends on what you are trying to do. OP hasn't specified any use case.

Comment: Yeah @Dharamraj

Comment: yes thanks for this . but my problem is not to get all users with due date passed. But when each user is signed in, it has a notification of  the invoice with due date passed. 
So my code is work fine, but when i'am connected with my email, i has the notification of the all users. so how can i get the current user id only?

Comment: @WafaBergaoui so you want to show notification only when user logs in? Then scheduled cloud functions is not ideal for this use case.

Comment: yes i think i will test this with callable function

Comment: @WafaBergaoui sure, let me know if you have any issues. If my answer to this question was helpful, you can accept it by clicking tick icon so others know it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You can get user id from the following `context.auth.id` in firebase functions.

```
const query = await db.collection("posts")
      .where("date", "==", date)
      .where("idUser", "==", context.auth.id) //something like this
      .get();
```

Comment: That's incorrect in case of Scheduled Cloud Functions. The auth property is null.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined