# "event.auth" equivalent in 2nd gen Firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to retrieve the uid (on server side) whenever a realtime database action is performed. I saw in the 1st Gen Firebase cloud functions, you can do it by accessing `context.auth.uid` as shown in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/extend-with-functions?gen=1st#accessing_user_authentication_information). But on the 2nd Gen, the docs didn't say. How should I do it?

Comment: Have a look at this Stackoverflow [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73788319/18265702) and [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67554532/18265702).

Comment: *firebaser here* I'm checking with the team, but from the lack of documentation it indeed seems that the auth context is no longer exposed to gen2 Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*firebaser here*

The 1st generation of Cloud Functions for Firebase indeed had a `context.auth`  parameter available for Realtime Database triggers that specifies the current user in the app at the time the database write was made.

There is currently no equivalent to this `context.auth` in the 2nd generation of Cloud Functions, due to the changes in the underlying architecture. So for the moment, you'll have to work around this in the same way you always had to for other trigger types: by passing the UID as part of the context/path, and ensuring that users can only write to their own UID through security rules. It's not terribly difficult, but a nuisance indeed given that this used to be built-in functionality.

There is internal interest to bring it back, so I recommend filing a feature request for it on [firebase.uservoice.com](https://firebase.uservoice.com) and with the [Firebase support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report).

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer Frank. The workaround suggested is limited and rules out applications with shared data and collaborative features. For these cases it seems we'll have to stick to the v1 API unless something changes. I've added my vote to the entry on the uservoice site